# Transfer from contract address to another address

Tags: erc-20

I created ERC-20 token, and send other ERC-20 token to created contract address.

Can I transfer that token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transferred tokens are not "in your contract".

Their amount is registered in the other contract, with a `mapping (address => uint256) balances`.

You can view that amount via `otherContract.balances[yourContractAddress]`, and you can transfer some or all of it by signing `otherContract.transfer` with the private key of `yourContractAddress`.

Unfortunately, the only way to retrieve the private-key of a deployed contract is by brute-force.

There are 2^256 different options, which is more or less the number of atoms in the known universe, so technically speaking, there is not enough energy in order to complete this kind of computation.

Comment: "Unfortunately" should actually be "Fortunately", because the whole Ethereum model would be worthless otherwise.

Comment: Thanks.
Other token created from me too. (I create two tokens).
If so can I transfer?

Comment: @HeesuCheon: No. You should have added a designated function in the other contract (typically with permission restricted only to your account), which performs this.

Comment: Thank you. `You should have added a designated function` means impossible now?

Comment: @HeesuCheon: For this deployment yes. You can always redeploy...